# jScrollPane how to store scroll position?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jscrollpane

I'm using the JQuery plugin jScrollPane.

A client has asked me if when a user scrolls the list of items, and clicks on one, then clicks back in their browser or goes back to that page from a menu, can the scroll box be at the same position. :S

This would mean storing the "top" css attribute computed by the plugin into a cookie on mouseUp (when they let go of the slider, store the value of "top") then when they return, I can check for that cookie and set it to that position.

That's the idea anyway, I've no idea even where to be begin with this.

Thanks for any responses. :)

Comment: _just start implementing your idea. 'coz while it is quite dumb - its well worth original client's demand ;) if you want some "improvements to it" - use `localStorage` instead of cookies, and `onunload` listener to make browser reload page on back button, instead of using cached version._ But seriously, if you can - just try to convince your client that its not a good idea at all. Together with behated jScrollPane..

Comment: Theoretical solution (which should work): Use http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/ to add a hash (#) to the URL with the numerical position of the scroll bar. Then use jquery to grab that hash from the url and use it to scroll to the correct position.

Alternatively you can use HTML5 history api + js to alter the URL https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my solution.

The position of the scrollbar is saved to localstorage, then when the page loads again, either by refresh or back from another page, if localstorage has a value greater than 0 which represents the top of the scrollbar (default, unscrolled position), it scrolls to that position.

```
var element = $(".scroll-pane").jScrollPane({showArrows:true});
if(element != undefined) {
  var api = element.data("jsp");
  $(function() {
    if(parseInt(localStorage.getItem("ScrollPosition")) > 0) {
      api.scrollToY(parseInt(localStorage.getItem("ScrollPosition")))
    }
    $(".scroll-pane").bind("jsp-scroll-y", function(event, scrollPositionY, isAtTop, isAtBottom) {
      localStorage.setItem("ScrollPosition", scrollPositionY)
    }).jScrollPane()
  })
}
;
```